# customize the person class (replace the username and password attributes)

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to replace the username with "email" and the password with "motDePasse" but I can't figure out how to do It: I tried to replace every old name by new name in the Person class and I added the following configuration to 
`my application.groovy :
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName= 'email'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordPropertyName= 'motDePasse'` 
but it doesn't work. I'm using grails 3.1.5, anyone can help me please?
the "*Custom UserDetailsService*" part of the documentation doesn't show how to replace attributes. 
Thank you

Comment: Are you getting errors when you run this or are you just not getting the expected results?

Comment: Yes, I finished by replacing just the email and keeping the password, it's working now, I will share what I did asap

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with keeping the default password and replacing the username with email, I had simply to replace every "username" with "email" in the Person class:

```
package ma.ac.uir.ecine.authentification

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString


@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='email')
@ToString(includes='email', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Personne implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String email
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Personne(String email, String password) {
        this()
        this.email = email
        this.password = password
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        PersonneRole.findAllByPersonne(this)*.role
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, password: true
        email blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

and add

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName= 'email'
```

to application.groovy
I couldn't replace the password.